# Can robot_localization package work well with just an IMU and a GPS?

Tags: imu, robot-localization, gps

Can robot-localization work with IMU and GPS for accurate localization? I have a highly accurate RTK-GPS. Is there a way to create the ekf config file such that the GPS data is used along with the IMU data to get a good velocity estimate?

Comment: This has been asked a bunch of times in the past. If you search for "robot_localization imu gps" in the search bar above, you'll likely find what you're looking for, e.g., https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/75672/fusing-imu-gps-with-robot-location-package